# create a hyperlink with php variable inside to open pdfs saved in folder with same name as table data

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a dynamic table raws with td's which is showing data from mysql data base.
Now i want to link a td in a tr to pdfs saved in my folder having similar name as td. As the name is not same always, i need to search within the folder with characters of td's available in tr to find the matching pdf on clicking td

Note: Folder is in htdocs/wells/

File examples:

htdocs/wells/AMGR-2/Composite200.pdf
htdocs/wells/AMGR-2/Composite500.pdf

[image: table where i want link]

```
<td width="230" class="left"> <a href="../loglib/wells/<?php echo $rowcd['no'] ?>/<?php echo $rowl['log'] ?>*<?php echo $rowl['scale'] ?>*.pdf"> <?php echo $rowl['log'] ?></td>
```

I tried this way

```
<table  id="singlewell" class="main">
    <thead>
        <tr >

            <th width="100">Well No</th>
            <th width="75">Well Name</th>
            <th width="100">Status</th>
            <th width="100">Issued to</th>
            <th width="75">Log #</th>
            <th width="230">Logs</th>
            <th width="50">Scale</th>
            <th width="40">BLI</th>
            <th width="40">TLI</th>
            <th width="100">Date of Log</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
while($rowcd = $resultw->fetch_assoc()){
 ?>
    <tr>

        <td align="center" width="100"><?php echo $rowcd['no'] ?></td>
        <td align="center" width="75"><?php echo $rowcd['name'] ?></td>
        <td colspan="8">

                        <table class="child">
                            <tr>
 <?php
$queryl = "select * from logs where pid=".$rowcd['id']." order by date desc";
//$queryl = "select * from logs where pid=".$rowcd['id'];
$resultl = $con->query($queryl);
while($rowl = $resultl->fetch_assoc()){
$dd = strtotime($rowl['date']);
$myFormatForView = date("d-m-Y", $dd);
    if($myFormatForView=='01-01-1970'){
       $myFormatForView1='';
       }else
       {
        $myFormatForView1=$myFormatForView;
        }
?>
<td width="100"><?php echo $rowl['status'] ?></a></td>
<td width="100"><?php echo wordwrap($rowl['rcvr'],10,"<br>\n",TRUE) ?</td>
<td width="75"><?php echo $rowl['lno']. "/" .$rowcd['rackno'] ?></td>
<td width="230" class="left"> <a href="../loglib/wells/<?php echo 
$rowcd['no'] ?>/<?php echo $rowl['log'] ?><?php echo $rowl['scale'] ? 
>.pdf"><?php echo $rowl['log'] ?></td>
<td width="50" align="center"><?php echo $rowl['scale'] ?></td>
<td width="40" align="center"><?php echo $rowl['bottom'] ?></td>
<td width="40" align="center"><?php echo $rowl['top'] ?></td>
<td width="100" align="center"><?php echo $myFormatForView ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<?php
}
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Show us the full code that you have tried

Comment: added the code as you asked

Comment: Anchor tag is not properly ended. Fix this and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

Now i am able to go to the specific folder, but i cannot access the specific file as the file name and the characters in td are not matching. (when it matches it opens, but as it is a big project i cannot go to each folder and rename the file as characters in td)

So i need sort of search in a directory with the keyword of characters in tds and the matching file should be opened

Comment: great .. could you please upvote me.